# Angular 7 - Splitting an Application into Modules and Lazy-loading

Tags: angular7

This is a descriptive question. I have read docs and have some conceptual issue:-

1) Is splitting of Application (for improved faster-loading and bundling and 
   performance) requires lazy-loaded implementation?

2) As I am loading component like below:-

```
   const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(cmptName).create(this.injector);
        this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
        const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
        document.querySelector('.mydynamicDiv').appendChild(domElem);
```

By calling components like this onclick in different different components requires splitting the application into several modules (keeping respective components in separate module). Currently, application have only one `app.module.ts` and `app.routing.ts`. Does this splitting into modules will improve performance. How?

3) Do we need to implement lazy-loaded routing as well in a `routing.ts`.

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'login', component: PrgLoginComponent },
        { path: 'login/:token/:id', component: PrgLoginComponent },
 { path: 'calendar', loadChildren: './prg-calendar/prg-calendar.module#PrgCalendarModule', canActivate: [PrgAuthGuardService] },
        { path: 'home', loadChildren: './prg-home/prg-home.module#PrgHomeModule', canActivate: [PrgAuthGuardService] }
    ]
}
```

However, Is Implementing above lazy-loaded routing like above  necessary as I will never route to modules like `calendar` above `using route`?

**So, only splitting the application into several modules with lazy-loaded routing(where some modules will never be accessed through routing but will directly called as above in point 2).Is it will improves performance and decrease bundling size.?**

**Keeping in mind above scenarion, should I split my app into several modules only. Or, lazy-loading using `loadchildren` is necessary for achieving the goal.?**

**Note:- I want to change route for my application view like once app get loaded for first time I want to keep url like- `www.abc.com/home`  ie `/home` will only route for every view.**

Any suggestion is appreciated?

Comment: Lazy loading modules is in fact only possible using the router. As you are working with AOT, its not possible to lazy load modules in a different way. The example in 2) requires the module content to be already compiled.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post your code for PrgCalendarModule?

Do you have a route in the Calendar Module?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CalendarComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PrgCalendarModuleRoutingModule { }
```

In the PrgCalendarModule

```
...
@NgModule({
imports: [
PrgCalendarModuleRoutingModule
]
...
```

Everything else looks fine from what you described.